# C - string, va_list

Tags: c, linux

I have write this code (simply). But it need of two fix to be ok.

```
size_t send_header(int fd, int seconds, const char* header1, ...) {
    char *buffer;
    int count = 0;
    const char * format = "%s";
    const char *hdr = header1;
    va_list vl, vl_count;
    va_start(vl, header1);

    va_copy(vl_count, vl);
    while (hdr != NULL) {
        hdr=va_arg(vl_count,const char*);
        ++count;
    }
    va_end(vl_count);
    /* allocate storage for format string: */
    buffer = (char*) malloc(strlen(format) * count + 1);
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    /* generate format string: */
    for (; count > 0; --count) {
        strcat(buffer, format);
    }
    /* print integers: */
    printf(format, header1);
    vprintf(buffer, vl);
    va_end(vl);
    if (BUFSIZ == 0) {
        _myfunc_errorcode(ERROR);
        return ERROR;
    }
    write(fd,buffer, strlen(buffer));
    _myfunc_errorcode(SUCCESS);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

1 FIX) this code print, the first time, at console this

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

the second time print at console this

```
(null)HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
```

where it add (null), i don't know very well.

2 FIX) fd,in write(), is a file descriptor that it use in other function but my browser show me only %s%s%s , why?

Thanks,regards

Comment: What is if (BUFSIZ == 0) { ?  it is not defined within the code.  How come your compiler did not flag this?

Comment: regarding this line (and the following line) _myfunc_errorcode(ERROR);  1( you should never (that is a bit strongly worded) create functions those name begins with an underscode. 2( ERROR is not defined in the code.  How come your compiler did not flag this?

Comment: regarding this line: buffer = (char*) malloc(strlen(format) * count + 1);  you should always check the results of a malloc() to assure that the operation was successful, before using the resulting pointer and heap memory and the format string in buffer will jam all the strings together.  Therefore I suggest modifying: format = "%s"; to: format = "%s \n";

Answer (score 1):

This is very confusing code.

This:

```
vprintf(buffer, vl);
```

is not a call to `vsprintf()`, so it won't format a string into `buffer`, it will just use `buffer` as the format string, read args from  `vl`, and print to stdout.

Yet you take the pain to *also* send out the format string in `buffer`, that long series of `%s`s, to `fd`. Of course you will see a bunch of `%s`s there.

I don't understand why this code goes through all the trouble just to build a formatting string full of repeated `%s` codes; it would be *so* much simpler to just print each string by yourself, than having `vprintf()` do it ...

Also, you leak the `buffer` memory since you never `free()` it.

Comment: Thanks! for reply! i have to create a reply http to starting from const char* header1,... i must re-assembly together, and later send inside fd, i know only this method. do you suggest other? And why all second time i have (null)? Thanks